# What can I do with elixir while I am maxing my Town Hall 9?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been Town Hall 9 for a few months now and it's come to the point where I have nothing left to upgrade that costs elixir and I'm unsure what to do with it now.

I've had people suggest all dragon raids, which would be fine, but they take far too long to train for my liking and I still need gold for various defenses and walls. I've been doing overnight dragon raids, but that still doesn't do much for me - I'm still gaining more than I'm losing.

Would it be better to just keep doing all dragon raids or stick my elixir storages outside walls? What do some of you do with your elixir when you don't need it?

Comment: Have you upgraded all of your troops?

Comment: Yes. I literally have nothing left at all to spend elixir on except for X-Bows, training troops, and spells.

Comment: I would upgrade my town-hall instead of wasting elixir on troops I don't really want. In the end its up to personal preference.

Comment: Fair enough. I could upgrade my Town Hall, but I really want to max out defenses first and at least level 8 walls. I have 2 air defenses, cannons, and archer towers left, and half way through my walls. If all goes to plan, I should be done in about a month or so. Was just curious if anybody had some creative solutions for worthless elixir. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade your town hall yet you could just donate heaps of good troops to your clan mates. Than you would get the "Friend in need" achievements pretty quickly.

Comment: I know, I'm in an odd situation, I guess. I farm with barbarians, archers, and minions, and do make donating armies now and again. I'm already well over the third Friend in Need achievement, haha. (72,462) That is a possibility, though, just make donating armies more often. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I would upgrade your Town Hall, even if some of the defenses are not fully upgraded. My Town Hall is no where near TH 9 (I'm a TH 6 now...) But I would upgrade your Town Hall and finish upgrading stuff later.

Comment: Try using it for your walls... supercell made it way more efficient upping walls with the multi upgrade and the elixir payment

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation (albeit at TH7).  I've got half my walls yet to upgrade, which is going to cost many millions in gold.  However, I just finished my last lab upgrade and don't have that much left to spend massive amounts of elixir on.

You've touched on higher cost raids in your question.  It is true that [BAM/BARCH](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) is a solid strategy, but it is very low cost in terms of elixir.

Right now you might want to focus on dark elixir and gold, so you may want to completely trash bigger, better defended bases for maximum loot.  Dragons take a crazy long time to train, but you might consider Giant/Healer or perhaps Balloonian raids to give you a bit more destructive potential and use up some of that elixir.

Having a whole bunch of elixir in your storages deep inside your base is a good way to get raided and completely trashed.  This is going to cost you gold and dark elixir, which is a bad thing.

Right now I've got my elixir storages outside of my walls, and I like that pretty well.  I've trapped them heavily, to get people to commit a lot of their troops to taking them down.  This tends to end with me earning trophies from them at a cost of elixir.  This has two benefits:

- Gaining trophies, which will give you bigger fish to fry when raiding and let you occasionally take resources from bases without getting a star
- Give you "sucker bases" to revenge when you're online.  Revenge is a powerful tool for finding bases where you can take your time, plan out a strategy, and take their stuff.

I wouldn't suggest preemptively upgrading your town hall unless you're sure you're ready for it.  Some of my clanmates have moved up early and found that the resource penalty causes them major issues.  This lengthens the time it takes to get enough resources together to make your upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent update will allow you to spend elixer to upgrade your walls at this level - problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I found an ingenious way to get rid of excess elixir. Start to upgrade something that uses elixir, like camps or barracks, but then cancel the upgrade. It will only return 50% of the price it takes to upgrade. This also keeps a builder free and doesnt take any time.

Comment: not sure why you would want to just throw away elixir, but I guess that would work.

Comment: This only works if you have still have stuff to upgrade that costs elixir. Although, this begs the question of: "why not just let it complete the upgrade?"

Answer (score 0):

What army comp are you using for farming? If you are using much DE consider switching to a pure E army.

I'm in a very similar position and I run the following:

- 16 giants
- 16 archers
- 32 barbs
- 23 wizards
- 4x healing potions

Hanging around Gold I this army comp allows me to wipe TH8 and below and take a fair amount of resources from TH9 and TH10. That along with troop donations has been enough to keep me in the 2-3 million range.

Also consider doing balloonion attacks in clan wars to spend more E.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble spending elixir and you have Pekka level 3 or 4, I would suggest to upgrade Pekka to level 10. This gives you a humongous benefit since a Pekka of level 10 can destroy everything in it's way.

Comment: Right now I'm only Town Hall 4 but I have gathered a lot of information before starting the game.

Comment: Pekkas cant get to level 10

Answer (score -1):

I suggest trying to sped it in research and even if you are overloaded on elixer, what's the harm? There's nothing wrong about it, anyway maybe upgrade camps and barracks to spend more